# Error saving the path of an image in my database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save the path of an image in my database, these images are generated with html2canvas and are saved in a directory, but when I generate them and save them in my database, a non-existent image name is generated and that is the one that stores me.

This is the code of how the image is saved in the database:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    include './save.php'; 
       
    $file = './images';
    $route = $file. "/". $imgName;

    $insert = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO  images (img) VALUES ('$route')");
    
    if ($insert) {
        echo "<script>alert('successfully registered image')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo '<script>("Ups...Something's wrong")</script>';
    }
}
```

This is the code that decodes the image for me and saves it in the folder:

```
$image = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


$image = $image->capture;

$image = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", urldecode($image));
$image = base64_decode($image); 

$imgName = "Image_" . uniqid() . ".png";

file_put_contents("images/$imgName", $image);
```

Comment: How are you getting the filename from the second code snippet to the first?

Comment: and the error is?

Comment: @aynber Could you be more clear, I'm quite new to php

Comment: What exactly is being saved in the database different than what you expected? What was it you expected? Do some `echo` of data along the way, and debug this. Are we to assume the second code snippet is in `include './save.php';` ?

Comment: @OldProgrammer That saves me an image that does not exist and not the one generated by html2canvas

Comment: Also, you are saving a file at `images/$imgName` ... but storing in the db `./images/$imgName` ... if you are not wanting the `./` then remove that from the db storage.

Comment: @IncredibleHat The second code fragment corresponds to the save.php file, which is where I receive the image in base64 and save it in the folder

Comment: @JuanManuel: When you debug, what is the runtime value of `$route` just before using it in the database operation, and how specifically does it differ from what you expect?